# How can I choose a capacitor for a very high energy pulse?

Tags: power, capacitor, heat, flash, pulse

I need to specify capacitors for a very high power pulse application. Specifically, I need to deliver a pulse of about 7 kJ over 5 ms at a voltage of about 1 kV DC, so peak current is off the charts. I can calculate how much capacitance I need, 14 mF with no problem, but I am struggling to find if an individual capacitor can actually handle the energy. Obviously, a small capacitor with small leads would blow up with the peak current, but amperage isn't something listed on many of the data sheets.

On the other hand, I could an array of 10 or 20 screw terminal capacitors in parallel and series to give the proper voltage and capacitance value, but where is the sweet spot for number required?

Edit: I realize these are dangerous power levels and shouldn't be attempted without proper safty protocols. Rice University used a bank of 10x 18 millifarad, 400 volt capacitors to get here, but that seems like overkill in that 14,400 joules would be stored. I am looking for advice on parallel vs series configurations from a cost, safety and performance standpoint

Comment: somewhat related: [What is the current when the capacitor terminals are shorted together?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/661188/7036)

Comment: What is the load? Does the voltage need to reverse (inductive load)? How many pulses lifetime? Rep rate?  Electrolytics may be feasible.  If that's a linear ramp, the current is about 3kA, or 0.2A per uF, beyond the RMS ratings of most any electrolytic but may be acceptable as an assumed peak value. Otherwise, you're looking at large canned or boxed polypropylene types, most likely. A budget under $10k should be enough even in the worst case.

Comment: Foil or possibly film polypropylene I believe is the only way. It'll be the size of a suitcase.

Comment: To add to @TimWilliams a nominal 20,000 Joule system that we designed in 2019 (40 kV/25uF) cost us $26k for caps with rush delivery.  In this case we sourced (2 caps ) at 12.5uF.  Each cap was 2-3 feet tall, with ~12x12 inch footprint.  One needs to tailor the system design to the desired output, consider control/switching characteristics and strategy, entire system impedance, reverse voltage considerations, cap protection and longevity estimates, and safety.

Comment: A polypropylene cap designed for pulse current applications will list a peak current. Some will allow a overcurrent (e.g. 50%) if the pulse is non-repetitive (pulses far enough apart so the temp returns to ambient).

Comment: To clarify a bit, this will be used for flash sintering, and making small amounts of graphene. The load is purely resistive, carbon powder, and load starts at 2 ohms and quickly goes down as carbon changed to graphene. Rice University did this with 10 off the shelf capacitors costing under $1,000. I was hoping to optimize the number and see if fewer could be used

Comment: At 5 ms, you are approaching the territory where ESL will start to dominate over ESR. Have you done any simulations including parasitics?

Comment: @GregSorter You should add this information in your question (and maybe add some more details and references). It seems that you are entering the territory where safety is a critical aspect of the design. Therefore the more information you give us the better the advices we can give you. Anyway, I wouldn't trust any random guy on the Internet for the actual design of a safety-critical application. If you don't have the in-house knowledge to do that, hire a professional. This may also "help" your legal team if anything goes horribly wrong.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, I took your advice and added some information